# Text overflowing from Bootstrap 4 row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

**EDIT:** As requested here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aqg1khLs/1/)

When the screen gets too small for the text to fit in the row, it just overlaps other rows, rather than extending the row height. Perhaps this is because I set row heights on every row as a percentage value, in order to lay out my html page with even spacing and vertical alignment. How do I correct this overlapping of text onto other rows? Should I be looking into somehow vertically aligning my rows without setting their height? Or can I keep it the way it is and add some kind of overflow property to each row to tell them to extend their height when necessary?

All relevant images and code:

screenshot of fullscreen (good - no problems yet)

[image]

screenshot of hovering over the middle row element on smaller screens (problems)

[image]

screenshot of hovering over the bottom row of smaller screens:

[image]

all my html for the page:

```
<div id="landing-page" class="text-uppercase">
    <div class="row hidden-lg-up" style="height:20%;overflow-y:auto;">
        <div class="col-xs-3 flex-xs-middle">
            <img width="100" src="images/monster2.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 offset-xs-6 flex-xs-middle">
            <img class="pull-xs-right" width="100" src="images/monster4.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="height:95%;overflow-y:auto;">
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-2 col-md-3 hidden-md-down flex-xs-top flex-sm-middle">
            <img width="80%" src="images/monster2.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 flex-xs-middle ">
            <div id="motto-text" style="text-align: center;">
                <h5 class="text-muted display-6">the vegan repository</h5>
                <h1 class="display-3">
                    find vegan stuff* near you.
                </h1>
                <a id="try-now-button" class="with-border clickable" href="#search-filter-page">
                    <h5 class="text-center medium-text">try now</h5>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-2 col-md-3 hidden-md-down flex-xs-top flex-sm-middle">
            <img class="pull-xs-right" width="80%" src="images/monster4.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="height:5%;overflow-y:auto;">
        <h4 class="display-6 flex-xs-bottom">
            *Stuff like restaurants, meat alternatives, dairy alternatives, and much more!
        </h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

all my css for the page:

```
div#landing-page {
    background-color: #696969;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 110px 40px 0px 40px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    min-height:470px;
}
```

**EDIT:** As requested here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aqg1khLs/1/)

Comment: Can you recreate the issue in a minimal example?

Comment: I dont see the problem. Here's http://www.bootply.com/DbLZ0mzPeQ I created for you with your code. You can use it to demo further the issue you're facing

Comment: @GHKarim Really? You don't see an issue with the images of the webpage in my question? Text is on top of text, and on top of images. Please view the images I posted in the question again. I don't understand why people are not seeing the issue. Your demo just disappears when resizing the screen to be small so I cannot test it under the right conditions.

Comment: Obviously there are two people who didn't read the whole question and one of them voted to close the question with the reason that it is not about programming :D

Comment: @Beniamino_Baggins lol, you took than one completely wrong. I meant I dont see how I can replicate the issue in bootply not in your post

Comment: @Beniamino_Baggins I am trying to help here!! so if it is not under the right condition, you'd probably better off demoing the issue using [Bootplay] (http://www.bootply.com/) or [JsFiddle] (https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @GHKarim I took it how it was written. You said you cannot see the problem so that's how I took it. I will work on a jsfiddle since bootplay doesn't seem to like resizing to be very small.

Answer (score 0):

Alright. Now the question is clear. The problem was easy to fix.

The problem is in the following div. You have specified it to have col-md-12 but you didn't force it when the screen is `xs`

```
 <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 flex-xs-middle ">
      <div id="motto-text" style="text-align: center;">
        <h5 class="text-muted display-6">the vegan repository</h5>
        <h1 class="display-3">
                    find vegan stuff* near you.
                </h1>
        <a id="try-now-button" class="with-border clickable" href="#search-filter-page">
          <h5 class="text-center medium-text">try now</h5>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

so the simplest thing is to add `col-xs-12` class to prevent overlapping

See [example](https://jsfiddle.net/aqg1khLs/2/)

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this changes the look of the website when it is viewed on large devices. On large devices the motto text must be only 6 columns wide, because I hide the top row which has the monster images, and I instead display the monster images on each side of the motto text. But I should still be able to do that without the text overlapping onto other rows somehow.